# C: scanf behavior in a for-loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I came across the following code :

```
int i;
for(; scanf("%s", &i);)
    printf("hello");
```

As per my understanding, if we provide integer input `scanf` would be unsuccessful in reading and therefore return 0, thus the loop should not run even once. However, it runs infinitely by accepting all types of inputs as successful reads.

Would someone kindly explain this behaviour?

Comment: please see the edit at the top of my answer. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is the incorrect format specifier for an `int`: should be `"%d"`.

It is attempting to read a string into an `int` variable, probably overwriting memory. As `"%s"` is specified, all inputs will be read thus `scanf()` returns a value greater than zero.

Answer (score 2):

(Edit: I **don't** think this answer should have been accepted. Upvoted maybe, but not accepted. It doesn't explain the infinite loop at all, @hmjd does that.)

(This doesn't actually answer the question, the other answers do that, but it's interesting and good to know.)

As hmjd says, using `scanf` like this will overwrite memory (["smash the stack"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow)), as it starts writing to `i` in memory, and then keeps going, even outside the 4 bytes of memory that `i` takes up (or 8 bytes, on a 64-bit platform).

To illustrate, consider the following bit of code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str_above[8] = "ABCDEFG";
    int i;
    char str_below[8] = "ABCDEFG";

    scanf("%s", &i);

    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    printf("str_above = %s\nstr_below = %s\n", str_above, str_below);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running it, and entering `1234567890` produces the following output:

```
i = 875770417
str_above = 567890
str_below = ABCDEFG
```

Some points:

- `i` has little correspondence to the integer `1234567890` (it is related to the values of the characters `'1'`,...,`'4'` and the endianness of the system).
- `str_above` has been modified by `scanf`: the characters `'5'`,...,`'0'`,`'\0'` have overrun the end of the block of memory reserved for `i` and have been written to the memory reserved for `str_above`.
- The stack has been smashed "upwards", i.e. `str_above` is stored later in memory than `i` and `str_below` is stored earlier in memory. (To put it another way `&str_above > &i` and `&str_below < &i`.)

This is the basis for "buffer overrun attacks", where values on the stack are modified by writing too much data to an array. And it is why `gets` is dangerous (and should *never* be used) and using `scanf` with a generic `%s` format specifier should also never be done.